# Building a 2D heatmap image from a 3D data set

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing, geospatial

I developed a script that creates X,Y points of concentric ellipses based on the `Area` of the ellipses and a number of other variables. I have also employed a function to create Z values which is based on the area of each ellipses. There is then a weighted correction `arf_w` applied to each value based on the area and Z value of the previous ellipse. The code is below:

```
import numpy as np

center_ft = (0, 0) #Center coordinates
area_mi = 0.5      #Area of largest ellipses
n_ellipses = 15    #Number of concentric ellipses
R = 0.01           #Reduction value for concentric ellipses
Duration = 3       #Variable for area reduction
Ratio = 2.25       #Major to minor axis length ratio
Theta = 45         #Angle of concentric ellipses about center

h, k = center_ft
Area_initial = area_mi * 5280**2

#Building largest ellipses
MinorAxis_initial = np.sqrt(Area_initial / (np.pi * Ratio))
MajorAxis_initial = Ratio * MinorAxis_initial

#Creating area and axis lengths lists for inner concentric ellipses
Area_List = np.linspace(R * Area_initial, Area_initial, n_ellipses).tolist()
Area_List = [x/5280**2 for x in Area_List]
MajorAxis_List = np.linspace(R * MajorAxis_initial, MajorAxis_initial, n_ellipses).tolist()
MinorAxis_List = np.linspace(R * MinorAxis_initial, MinorAxis_initial, n_ellipses).tolist()

x = []
y = []
z = []
arf = []
for (a, b, Area, i) in zip(MajorAxis_List, MinorAxis_List, Area_List, range(n_ellipses)):
  t = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
  x0 = a * np.cos(t) * np.cos(Theta) - b * np.sin(t) * np.sin(Theta) + h #x coordinates
  y0 = a * np.cos(t) * np.sin(Theta) + b * np.sin(t) * np.cos(Theta) + k #y coordinates
  arf0 = 0.01 * (100 - Duration * (Area**0.46)) #reduction equation
  z0 = np.ones(len(t))*arf0

  arf.append(arf0)
  x.append(x0)
  y.append(y0)
  z.append(z0)

#Weighted reduction factor developed from inner ellipses 
arf_w = []
for (i) in range(n_ellipses):
  arf_w0 = (arf[i-1] * Area_List[i-1] - Area_List[i] * arf [i]) / (Area_List[i-1] - Area_List[i])
  arf_w.append(arf_w0)
arf_w[0] = arf[0]

for i in range(n_ellipses):
  z[i] = arf_w[i]*np.ones(len(t))
```

The goal is to produce an image of a heat map that has each concentric ellipses filled in based on its equivalent Z value `arf_w`. Ultimately this would be used as a .tiff for applications in a geospatial information software. I think I have a good start with a function that produces concentric ellipses but have run into a wall moving the concentric ellipses to an image. I am familiar with libraries such as:

https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.draw.html#skimage.draw.ellipse

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.ellipse

I haven't had luck replicating the concentric ellipses pattern based on the variables I want to employ from the ellipses functions in those libraries. Attached is a plot of the concentric ellipses plotted with `matplotlib`, the code for plotting is removed but wanted to show an example of the results from the code. The image would look something like the plot but each ellipses would be filled in with a color until the next ellipses based on its respective `arf_w`. Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

[image: Concentric ellipses plotted with matplotlib]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what needs to happen with the `arf` and `arf_w` values but you should be able to adapt this code to your needs:

```
x_range = 2000
y_range = 3000
x = np.linspace(-x_range,x_range,1000)
y = np.linspace(-y_range,y_range,1000)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = np.zeros_like(X)

# use quadratic form for inside of ellipse
cT = np.cos(Theta)
sT = np.sin(Theta)
U = X*cT+Y*sT
V = X*sT-Y*cT
for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(MajorAxis_List[::-1], MinorAxis_List[::-1])):
    u = U/a
    v = V/b
    mask = u*u + v*v <= 1
    Z[mask] = i # edit here with appropriate value

plt.figure(2).clf()
plt.imshow(Z, origin="lower", extent=(-x_range+h, x_range+h, -y_range+k, y_range+k))
```

Note the `[::-1]` in the loop to ensure not overwriting points from smaller ellipse with the larger one.